# Images should remain in center of the tab view on screen size in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, responsive, picturebox, tabview

I have a tab-control and it contains 1 tab view and in it there are 3 different picture-boxes which contain the 3 different images, besides each other, now the thing is that I have set the picture-boxes according to my monitor settings, but what I want is the form and picture boxes should remain exactly the same as per any screen settings, either it is low resolution or high, I tried and achieved one of the picture-boxes, but not able to set the other accordingly, can any body show me how to do it?. Images should remain in center of the tab view accordingly like this.

[image]

```
        Bitmap b = new Bitmap(500, 500);
        pbox_View_Angle.Size = b.Size;
        var left = (tabPage1.ClientRectangle.Width - pbox_View_Angle.ClientRectangle.Width) / 4;
        var top = (tabPage1.ClientRectangle.Height - pbox_View_Angle.ClientRectangle.Height) / 2;
        pbox_View_Angle.Location = new Point(tabPage1.ClientRectangle.Location.X + left, tabPage1.ClientRectangle.Location.Y + top);

        pbox_View_Height.Location = new Point(tabPage1.ClientRectangle.Location.X + left + 400, tabPage1.ClientRectangle.Location.Y + top);

        pbox_View_Azimuth.Location = new Point(tabPage1.ClientRectangle.Location.X + left + 800, tabPage1.ClientRectangle.Location.Y + top);`
```

Comment: Writing code that is dpiAware is very, very important today.  Something that Winforms programmers tend to discover early, the designer runs inside VS which is a dpiAware app.  But they forget to [mark their own app to be dpiAware](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13228495/17034), so the UI gets rescaled to 96 dpi.  Discovering the bugs is otherwise useful, helps you find out what happens on another user's machine.  The code has a bug, hard-coding 400 and 800 is not correct when it gets rescaled.  Easy fix, either stop helping or add pbox_View_Angle.Width.

Comment: Thank you, understood, but not much clear on dpiAware, will check it and let you know.

Comment: Are the pboxes anchored? They probably shouldn't be.

Comment: No, not anchored.